# is better off/served without you

Tags: word-choice, phrase-usage

> *This company is better off/served without you. I hope you get fired.*

Would "is better off without you" and "is better served without you" both be perfectly natural in this context? Are there differences between them?

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are asking for the sake of writing a novel, not for real!

"Better off" or "better served" are both possible.  "Better served" is rather formal, and could be used in a formal expression such as "The company would be better served by you leaving your employment". We tend to say "would be better served by ...."

But that doesn't fit with "Fired". So for consistency of style I'd use "Better off".

But this is fighting talk. It is the sort of comment that can start a brawl.

Answer (score 0):

The expressions *"better off"* and *"better served"* are natural and grammatically correct, and they mean the same thing. However, "better served" is quite formal, which clashes in style with the very rude, "I hope you get fired", so these two wouldn't normally appear together, except maybe coming from a condescending Disney villain. So in this context, "better off" sounds better because it can be used in informal contexts.